# Set alpha value to text on Action.Bar when selected

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to set alpha value on a tab when is selected using

```
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            tab.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
            //tab.getTextView().setAlpha(255);
      }

      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            tab.getIcon().setAlpha(30);
            //tab.getTextView().setAlpha(30);
      }
```

The problem is i would also want the TextView of the tab to be just like that, but Tab doesn't have a getTextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom view to the `ActionBar.Tab` which would be a `TextView`.

Alternatively, you can create `SpannableString` and supply a color span , where the color has alpha channel (ARGB), and of course have different alpha value when the tab is selected.

Comment: SpannableString seems a clean way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: I feel sorry for ActionBar.Tab does not honor spannables, rather than CharSequence. Is adding `TextView` as custom view too much work?

Comment: Can't find an example to create a custom view Tab to be exactly the same as default.

Comment: It is TextView with MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP_CONTENT for height, the text is positioned at the center with gravity="center". :)

Comment: I'm using http://pastebin.com/RJdCrwUY, still i'm getting weird look http://imgur.com/S4VLXDz.jpg and it should look like http://imgur.com/v9GjrDn.jpg

Comment: Try adding a padding of 16dp

Comment: 16dp shows the icon cut in half, so i correct it to 10dp, now looks the same :) Thanks a lot!